# Can I make this AutoHotKey qwerty-half keyboard script work with caps-lock on?

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I found this script at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/1257-half-qwerty-one-handed-typing/

What this script does is it remaps the spacebar to be a modifier. When space is held, the keyboard is inverted, with the line of symmetry between g and h. Thus, e would become i, b would become n, p would become q, and so on. If the spacebar is depressed and released without pressing any other keys, a single space is sent. Modifier keys such as shift or control can be used in conjuction with Half-qwerty.

The problem is, it doesn't work for capital letters while caps lock is on.

Any help would be awesome!!

```
;QWERTY half-keyboard emulator

mirror_1 = 0
mirror_2 = 9
mirror_3 = 8
mirror_4 = 7
mirror_5 = 6
mirror_q = p
mirror_w = o
mirror_e = i
mirror_r = u
mirror_t = y
mirror_a = `;
mirror_s = l
mirror_d = k
mirror_f = j
mirror_g = h
mirror_z = /
mirror_x = .
mirror_c = ,
mirror_v = m
mirror_b = n
mirror_6 = 5
mirror_7 = 4
mirror_8 = 3
mirror_9 = 2
mirror_0 = 1
mirror_y = t
mirror_u = r
mirror_i = e
mirror_o = w
mirror_p = q
mirror_h = g
mirror_j = f
mirror_k = d
mirror_l = s
mirror_n = b
mirror_m = v


;This key may help, as the space-on-up may get annoying, especially if you type fast.
Control & Space::Suspend

;These keys are optional, but they may help if you are typing on the left-hand side.

CapsLock::Send, {BackSpace}
+Capslock::Capslock
;Capslock is backspace and Shift+Capslock works for Capslock.

Space & `::Send, {-}  

Space & CapsLock::Send, {Enter}

If spacebar didn't modify anything, send a real space keystroke upon release.
space::
Send {space}
return

space & 1::
space & 2::
space & 3::
space & 4::
space & 5::
space & q::
space & w::
space & e::
space & r::
space & t::
space & a::
space & s::
space & d::
space & f::
space & g::
space & z::
space & x::
space & c::
space & v::
space & b::
space & `;::
space & ,::
space & .::
space & /::
space & 6::
space & 7::
space & 8::
space & 9::
space & 0::
space & y::
space & u::
space & i::
space & o::
space & p::
space & h::
space & j::
space & k::
space & l::
space & n::
space & m::
;Determine the mirror key, if there is one:
if A_ThisHotkey = space & `;
   MirrorKey = a
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & ,
   MirrorKey = c
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & .
   MirrorKey = x
else if A_ThisHotkey = space & /
   MirrorKey = z
else  ; To avoid runtime errors due to invalid var names, do this part last.
{
   StringRight, ThisKey, A_ThisHotkey, 1
   StringTrimRight, MirrorKey, mirror_%ThisKey%, 0  ; Retrieve "array" element.
   if MirrorKey =  ; No mirror, script probably needs adjustment.
      return
}


Modifiers =
GetKeyState, state1, LWin
GetKeyState, state2, RWin
state = %state1%%state2%
if state <> UU  ; At least one Windows key is down.
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%#
GetKeyState, state1, Control
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%^
GetKeyState, state1, Alt
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%!
GetKeyState, state1, Shift
if state1 = D
   Modifiers = %Modifiers%+
Send %Modifiers%{%MirrorKey%}
return
```

Note that AutoHotKey variable names are NOT case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
; Associative array that mirrors the left and right side of the keyboard.
keyA    :=  {"1" : "0"
            ,"2" : "9"
            ,"3" : "8"
            ,"4" : "7"
            ,"5" : "6"
            ,"q" : "p"
            ,"w" : "o"
            ,"e" : "i"
            ,"r" : "u"
            ,"t" : "y"
            ,"a" : ";"
            ,"s" : "l"
            ,"d" : "k"
            ,"f" : "j"
            ,"g" : "h"
            ,"z" : "/"
            ,"x" : "."
            ,"c" : ","
            ,"v" : "m"
            ,"b" : "n"
            ,"0" : "1"
            ,"9" : "2"
            ,"8" : "3"
            ,"7" : "4"
            ,"6" : "5"
            ,"p" : "q"
            ,"o" : "w"
            ,"i" : "e"
            ,"u" : "r"
            ,"y" : "t"
            ,";" : "a"
            ,"l" : "s"
            ,"k" : "d"
            ,"j" : "f"
            ,"h" : "g"
            ,"/" : "z"
            ,"." : "x"
            ,"," : "c"
            ,"m" : "v"
            ,"n" : "b"}

; Make Hotkeys
for index, value in keyA
    Hotkey, % "$*" index, FlipFlop, On
return

; Disables space from being sent if it's held down for more than 300ms
$*Space::
    KeyWait, Space, T0.3
    if (ErrorLevel = 1)
        KeyWait, Space
    Else
        Send, {Space}
return

; Removes the hook and wildcard modifiers
FlipFlop:
    StringReplace, hk, A_ThisHotkey, % "$*"
    ; If space is held
    if GetKeyState("Space", "P")
        ; Send the mirror of the keys along with any held modifiers
        Send, % "{Blind}" keyA[hk]
    Else
        ; Send the actual key pressed along with modifiers
        Send, % "{Blind}" hk
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative Array instead off `mirror_a` etc. and include the capital letters as well.